# Asp.net asmx file throws error in design view

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, visual-studio-2012

I had an asp.net web forms website which was working fine. I wanted to convert it into a web application. So I have created a new web application and copied all the code files from the web site to the web application. There was one .cs file in the app_code folder which is used as a webservice. This one is causing issue. The code compiles. However when I see the files in design view, I get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error. When I expand the "Show Call Stack" link, I see the following:

at   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.MergedCodeDomParser.System.CodeDom.Compiler.ICodeParser.Parse(TextReader stream)
at System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider.Parse(TextReader codeStream)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.CodeDomDocDataAdapter.get_CompileUnit()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
   at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.BasicDesignerLoader.BeginLoad(IDesignerLoaderHost host)

```
The following is part of the code:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.UI;
using Telerik.Web.UI;


[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]

[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class CustomWebService : WebService
{
[WebMethod]
public string GetOrderDetails(object context)
{
    var contextDictionary = (IDictionary<string, object>)context;
    var orderID = (string)contextDictionary["Value"];

    var orderDetails = GetData_OrderDetails(orderID);

    var path = "~/UserControls/";

    return ViewManager.RenderView(path + "OrderDetails.ascx", orderDetails);
}


[WebMethod]
public string GetCustomerDetails(object context)
{
    var contextDictionary = (IDictionary<string, object>)context;
    var customerID = (string)contextDictionary["Value"];

    var cs = GetData_CustomerDetails(customerID);

    var path = "~/UserControls/";

    return ViewManager.RenderView(path + "CustomerDetails.ascx",  cs);        
}


[WebMethod]
public RadTreeNodeData[] GetTreeViewCustomers(RadTreeNodeData node, object     context)
{
    var contextDictionary = (IDictionary<string, object>)context;
    var country = (string)contextDictionary["Country"];
    var countries = GetData_CustomerByCountry(country);

    var result = new List<RadTreeNodeData>();

    foreach (DataRow row in countries.Rows)
    {
        var itemData = new RadTreeNodeData();
        itemData.Text = row["ContactName"].ToString();
        itemData.Value = row["CustomerID"].ToString();
        result.Add(itemData);
    }

    return result.ToArray();
}
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Does root + /UserControls/OrderDetails.ascx exist?

Comment: Yes, it exists.Thanks

Comment: You don't mention which VS version you're doing, but there is a workaround and some helpful comments here.  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2010/05/06/another-error-creating-control-in-the-design-view-with-object-reference-not-set-in-visual-studio-2010/

Comment: It is VS 2015 Community Edition. Thanks

Comment: How about this post/answer?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23695733/windows-forms-designer-nullreferenceexception-where-to-go-from-here

Comment: Hmm strangely when I right click the file and chose "Clean Code" the design page error went away. However when I ran the application, I am getting "Cannot serialize member Telerik.Web.UI.ControlItemData.Attributes of type System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Object, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] because it is an interface." error

Comment: Change RadTreeNodeData to object in the return type and parameter for GetTreeViewCustomers()     http://www.telerik.com/forums/radcombobox-load-on-demand-with-web-service#732428

Comment: Hi Sean, Now I am getting The Server method GetTreeViewCustomers failed error. The debugger doesn't even go to this method. Thansk

Comment: Did you  find a fix for this?  I'm seeing the same, but with a fairly vanilla ASMX vb file.  No Telerik stuff involved. Feeling stumped.